# Working with little $o$ notation.

Tags: proof-explanation, asymptotics

I’m reading a text which contains the following computation:

> $$\text{log}n - (1 + \epsilon)\text{log}n + o(\text{log}n) = - \ (1 + o(1))\ \epsilon \ \text{log}n$$

Here  $\epsilon$ could be taken to be $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\text{loglogloglog}n}$, and $f = o(\text{log}n)$ is understood as $\frac{f}{\text{log}n} \to 0$.

To get there, I’m thinking it’s necessary for the author to have used $o(\text{log}n) = - o(1) \ \epsilon \ \text{log}n$. While it’s true that $\frac{- o(1) \ \epsilon \ \text{log}n}{\text{log}n} \to 0$, I’m not sure I understand when it’s okay to replace the LHS with an expression like the RHS above (as the RHS seems to contain more information). In general, for ease of computation, does any function $f$ could be used, as long as $\frac{f}{\text{log}n} \to 0$?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ in your expression? number, function?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah That’s true. But then the question would be to justify that $o(\text{log}n)$ is equivalent to $o(1) \ \epsilon \ \text{log}n$.

Comment: @zkutch the note says that $\epsilon$ could be taken to be $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\text{loglogloglog}n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Little-$o$ definition, taking for sequences, is set
$$o(f)=\{g\colon \exists\varepsilon(n), \lim\limits_{n \to\infty } \varepsilon(n)=0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n>N, g(n)= \varepsilon(n)\cdot f(n)\}$$
based on this definition can be shown, that holds properties
$$c\cdot o(f)=o(c\cdot f)=o(f)$$
for $c$ constant. And most important for this case
$$o(g)\cdot o(f)=o(g\cdot f)$$

Some more properties can be find at [Little-o_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)

In your case from first expression we obtain
$$\log n - (1 + \epsilon)\log n + o(\log n) =-\epsilon \log n + o(\log n) = (-\epsilon +o(1))\log n$$
So, without logarithm, here we have set $\{-\epsilon + \phi\}$, where $\phi\to 0$

On right hand we have $-(1+o(1))\epsilon \log n$, so, without logarithm, we have set $\{-\epsilon + \epsilon\phi\}$.

We have $o(\epsilon) \subset o(1)$, when $\epsilon \to 0$, but $o(1)\not\subset o(\epsilon)$, so equality can't be written: $o(\epsilon) \ne o(1)$.

Comment: So it’s because $\epsilon (n) \to 0$ in my example, that the computation can be done?

Comment: Now adding, give few min, pls..